# How to get value from URL in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Routes.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::get('/age/{val}','AgeController@store');
```

AgeController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AgeController extends Controller
{
//

   public function store(Request $request)
    {

       $data = $request->input('val');
       var_dump($data); 
    }
}
```

My url is `localhost/lara/public/age/20`.

but

```
output:array(0) { }
```

When I change `$request->input('val',500);`

then output: `int(500)`

How to get 20 (val) in controller? Why array empty?

Answer (score 0):

If your controller method is also expecting input from a route parameter, simply list your route arguments after your other dependencies. Add `$val` as the 2nd parameter in you store function. In your case it should be

```
public function store (Request $request,$val){dd($val);}
```